# ReactJS children - filter out null values

Tags: reactjs

I'm rendering my components with:

```js
<PanelGroup>
    {this.renderPanel1()}
    {this.renderPanel2()}
    {this.renderPanel3()}
</PanelGroup>
```

Now one of my panels is only available if its available-property is set to `true`. The render()-method otherwise returns null.

My `<PanelGroup>` should add a divider on the bottom of all elements except in the last element.

I tried to accomplish that with the following code, but because even if `panel2` is returning null, the divider is still added, and the code won't work.

How can I filter out all my panels which are returning null? :)

```js
<div>
   {React.Children.map(
       React.Children.toArray(props.children),
           (child: React.ReactElement<PanelProps>, i) => {
               return (
                     <div>
                        {React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<PanelProps>, child.props)}
                        {/*Add divider after all elements except last*/}
                        {i < React.Children.count(props.children) -1 && <Divider/>}
                     </div>
                )
           }
        )}
</div>
```

Comment: where do you set the available `prop`? maybe the logic for the `available` prop can be used for the filtering...

Comment: still searching :D

Comment: by the way you can directly pass `props.children` into `React.Children.map`, no need to call `React.Children.toArray`

Comment: Olivier, then im getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of

```
{i < React.Children.count(props.children) -1 && <Divider/>}
```

i tried

```
{i < React.Children.toArray(props.children).length - 1 && <Divider/>}
```

thats working.
toArray removes null values.

Answer (score 15):

You have to take advantage of *Array.filter()*:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ children }) => {
  // This filter will return only not null values
  const children = React.Children.toArray(children).filter(Boolean);
  
  // return ...
};
```

Working example:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,null,4,null,5,null];
console.log(array.filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: hey Mosè, still wont work when i add the filter. is o => o enough?

Comment: o => o  is enough to filter null values, print the array before filter and check that is a plain array with null elements as o => o will check if the element itself in collection is empty, not one of its properties

Comment: This is *not* answering the question. He's talking about rendering out a componet which isn't actually null it's a component that renders null has a `() => null` value. So it is considered truthy.

Answer (score 0):

**children is not an array and cannot be treated as such (except by React.children).**

**If you try to filter nulls using standard Array techniques it will not work !**

I just lost some time to this.

The issue I had was that I was treating children as an array, then doing some ramda reject all the nulls, and it wouldn't work.

As soon as I did a `React.children.toArray(children)` as the input to my "reject the nulls" filter all was well.

Imagine 2 children, where one was null, generated from something like this:

```
<PanelGroup>
    {this.renderPanel1()}
    {false && this.renderPanel2()}
</PanelGroup>
```

In my panel group renderer:

```
console.log(children.length) // 2
console.log(R.reject(R.isNil, children).length) // 2
console.log(R.reject(R.isNil, React.Children.toArray(children)).length) // 1
```

yields:

```
2
2
1
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Having tried the other answers this is what I have found to work.

```js
const filteredChildren = Children.toArray(children)
    .filter((child: any) => Boolean(child.type() !== null));
```